# Strange behavior in ViewPager (bug?)

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

While trying to use addOnPageChangeListener from a class different to where the ViewPager is, I notice that it causes a strange behavior... the instructions get executed several times after the first time they are called. I made a pretty much auto-generated sample project so you can see for yourself:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.laptop.test;

import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    static ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return  new TestActivity();
                case 1:
                    return new TestActivity2();
                case 2:
                    return new TestActivity2();
            }    return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

TestActivity.java:

```
package com.example.laptop.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TestActivity extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
    }
```

TestActivity2.java:

```
package com.example.laptop.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestActivity2 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    int i=0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test2, container, false);

        MainActivity.mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                if(position==1){

                    Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(),i+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    i++;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
    }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.laptop.test.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_test.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 1"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_test2.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 2"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As shown in TestActivity2, the system should release a Toast showing a number when page 2 is reached, adding 1 to the variable each time the page is reached, and that's it. The first swipe to page 2 does just that, but in subsequent swipes the output gets weirder and weirder, with several toasts being shown instead of just one.

Additional to this, I noticed that when the quantity of pages is 2 instead of 3 the problem goes away.

Does this problem happen only to me?, how can I have a work around around this?, is this a bug or is it expected and there's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I've got to say, having a static reference to a view is a source of memory leaks and headaches. Consider registering your `OnPageChangeListener` in your activity and then pass data to your fragments as of documentation and tutorials here: [Communicating with other fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

About the issue at hand, the problem is also arising because of your static `ViewPager`. You're adding reference to your fragments, inside a static variable, so those fragments never get garbage collected and they alongside the `OnPageChangeListener` lives as long as that static variable. So when `ViewPager` creates a new fragment, the `OnPageChangeListener` of the last one still lives, hence the multiple toasts.

`ViewPager` by default load 2 pages into memory, you can change this by `setOffscreenPageLimit(int)`. When you have 3 pages, one of them get destroyed and renewed when you visit it (or the page before it). And this is the root cause of what I described above.

You can resolve this issue by registering only one OnPageChangeListener in your activity, making the ViewPager a non-static field and then notify your fragments of the changes by the means which you can learn about in the link I initially pointed out to you.

Optionally, you can take look at [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) as an alternative way of communicating with your fragments.

Comment: I've been posting and deleting this question for days and you were the only one with an answer, thank you very much!

I'm so far alone in Android development and I don't want to be pushy but can we keep in touch?. I promise I'll only bother you when a I have a problem that I can't make work in any way.

Comment: Glad to be of help.
Unfortunately that's not possible for me right now. StackOverflow is the only place I can provide help.
Good luck and happy coding! @LuchitoMarcano